# genetic algorithm with outer fitness function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use genetic algorithm in Matlab app in order to solve an optimization problem.i don't have the fitness function.what i have is a model from Vensim software.population enter to the Vensim model and the output is fitness function.we have 10 chromosome that have 10 value for fitness function.what kind of commands we can use in Matlab that match each fitness value with its own chromosome. 
for example:
my new population is : [1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]
my fitness function values is: [100;200;300]
i want calculate chromosome(1,2,3) with 100 values fitness function. or first rows of matrix population = first of rows matrix fitness function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
population = [1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9];
fitness_function = [100;200;300];
for ii = 1:length(fitness_function)
    chromosome = population(ii,:);
    fitness_value = fitness_function(ii);
    result = calculate(chromosome, fitness_value);
end
```

Comment: :Thx, 
what is pupolation variable?

Comment: @user3857554 Oh i'm sorry.... I mean pick one chromosome from the `population` matrix.

Comment: I get this error message: Undefined function 'calculate' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: You need some careful thinking about your problem, not simply copying and pasting the code.

Comment: after this code, I get this error:
Undefined function 'calculate' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Nind=10; 
MAXGEN=1;
NVAR=24; 
population = fix(10000*rand(10,24));
fitness_function =  fix(10000*rand(10,1));
for ii = 1:length(fitness_function)
    chrom = population(ii,:);
    fitness_value = fitness_function(ii);
    result = calculate(chrom, fitness_value);
end

Comment: `i want calculate chromosome(1,2,3) with 100 values fitness function.` That's what you said.